# NSPredicate to filter out results by property that exists only in one of the subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is it possible to write a predicate that would filter out objects by property that exists only in one of the subclasses (in CoreData).

For example:

```
class MainClass: NSManagedObject {
    vars...
}

class Subclass1: MainClass {
    vars...
}

class Subclass2: MainClass {
    var isImportant: NSNumber
}
```

I would like to write a predicate that would return `MainClass` type objects but would filter out `Subclass2` objects whose property `isImportant` is set to `false`.

So resulting array of objects should include all `MainClass` and `Subclass1` objects. But only `Subclass2` objects whose `isImportant` property is set to `true`.

I need to write similar predicate for fetch request for `NSFetchedResultsController` in CoreData.

Comment: Perhaps, the design is wrong here. Could you explain how your entities would look like?

Answer (score -1):

Chapter 3 of https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/ goes into details about *subentities*, but basically: You almost never want to use them. You can create subclasses (like you do) without using subentities. That might solve your problem.